# How to update domain password cache over vpn

Tags: domain, password, login, cache, windows-xp

I have a machine that connects to a domain over a VPN, however it hasn't connected for months and has an old domain password (that I have forgotten) cached on it and won't let me log in to the box with my domain account and my current password.  I can log in to the box as local administrator, and from there connect to the domain via the VPN, but how can I update/refresh the password on the domain account so I can log in again?  Logging off disconnects me from the VPN.  I'm running windows XP SP3.  Here's what I've tried that hasn't worked:

1) Logging in as administrator, connecting to the VPN, locking the machine, and unlocking with the domain account/new password.  The domain account is an administrator on the local box, but it can't unlock.

2) Logging in as administrator, connecting to the VPN, removing and re-adding the domain account as an admin (this requires me to type in my domain account/new password, but I still can't log in using the domain account).

3) Remembering the old password...  just not happening

Any ideas short of dragging the machine to work and connecting to the domain without the VPN?

Comment: Did you try to remove the domain user from that xp machine and then add it back? Also try to delete the local stored profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XP you can connect to the VPN *first* and *then* login (from the ctrl-alt-del). Just hit ctrl-alt-delete and check the "Log on Using dial-up connect" to get the VPN choice. Connect VPN, then log-in with current domain creds.

I should qualify that a bit. I know you can if you using the built-in VPN client. I'm assuming the same applies with 3rd party clients as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what you use as your VPN client, but if you use Cisco VPN there is an option to launch the VPN client before logging into the machine, if you can connect to the VPN before logging into the machine you should be able to use the current valid domain password.